# How use electron-tabs lib with electron-react-boilerplate?

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I installed the electron-tabs lib on electron-react-boilarplate and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRNxA.png) error occurs:

App.tsx

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import { TabGroup } from 'electron-tabs';

const App: FC = () => {
  const tabGroup = new TabGroup();
  const tab = tabGroup.addTab({
    title: 'electron-tabs on NPM',
    src: 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-tabs',
  }) as any;

  return tab;
};

export default App;
```